# Вывод элементов массива по 2 за раз. JS

Tags: javascript, массивы

Есть массив:

```
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
```

По клику, должно выводиться по два элемента в консоль:

```
12
34
56
78
```

Как это реализовать ?

Comment: Если у вас в массиве будет нечетное число элементов, что должно быть в последней паре?

Answer (score 3):

Ну например так:

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
                    
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    console.log(arr[i], 
                arr[++i]);
}
```

Вывод:

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
```

Ну а по клику, это уже вам нужно обернуть например в функцию и уже на клик по вешать.

Comment: Если у вас в массиве будет нечетное число элементов, в конце будет undefined.

Comment: @Anamnian, это пример, а исправить тут не составит никакого труда.

Answer (score 1):

> По клику, должно выводиться по два элемента в консоль. Как это реализовать ?

Вот так например:

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
// Элемент 
var d = document.querySelector('.clk')
var i = 0; // Счётчик
// Вешаем событие клик
d.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (i < arr.length) { // i в размере массива
    console.log(arr[i++], arr[i]);
    i++;
  } else { // обнуляем на следующий круг
    i = 0;
  }
})
```

```css
.clk {
  background: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="clk"></div>
```